# MYSQL Order by sum of different table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

cat_seriale - which represents the serial categories and provides ID's for each category like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

seriale - which is actual tv serials, and each tv serial falls in one category.

I am trying to

```
SELECT * FROM cat_seriale WHERE `id`='1'
```

and additionally to all columns, display the sum of `views` column from all rows in seriale table.

If some one can help me out, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

SCHEMA:

```
cat_seriale columns: 
Primary Key - catid(int)
catname (varchar)
...

seriale columns:
Primary Key - id(int)
cat (int)
views(int)
```

I need to select cat_seriale where ID = 1, and select sum of views in seriale columns where cat is same with id from cat_seriale.

Comment: Provide schema for both `cat_seriale` and `seriale` tables.

Comment: done ;) hope its okay, its my first time explaining mysql questions

Comment: `SELECT cat_seriale.*, SUM(seriale.views) FROM cat_seriale LEFT JOIN seriale ON seriale.cat = cat_seriale.catid WHERE cat_seriale.catid = 1`  ?

Comment: In the end i got this: SELECT *, SUM(seriale.views) FROM cat_seriale LEFT JOIN seriale ON seriale.cat = catid WHERE catid = 1

Comment: @Mike: No, you don't—here we're grouping on all rows by virtue of the `WHERE` condition filtering by PK of `cat_seriale`.

Comment: What happens if i need to select more than one row? This is not working on multiple rows :(

Comment: @eggyal Only if config ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled. On new version of MySQL may by _enabled_ by default

Comment: Should it be `id = 1` or `catid = 1`?

Comment: @Mike: Actually, on latest MySQL even with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` it will still work because MySQL is smart enough to detect the non-aggregated columns are all functionally dependent on the filtered PK.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
select *, (select sum(views) from seriale S where S.cat=C.catid) as sum_views
  from cat_seriale C
 where id='1'
 order by sum_views
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables.

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(s.views) AS views
FROM cat_seriale AS c
LEFT JOIN seriale AS s ON c.catid = s.cat
WHERE c.id = `1`
GROUP BY c.catid
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @Mike answer, but this version has more performance:

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(s.views) as summary
FROM cat_seriale c
LEFT JOIN seriale s ON s.cat = c.catid
WHERE c.id = '1'
GROUP BY c.catid 
ORDER BY summary
```

Comment: What's the point of grouping by the same field that you're selecting in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, it was typo

Comment: @Barmar if there is no group by, only one row will be displayed.

Comment: @RuslanDascal That was about a previous edit. He used the same column in `WHERE` as `GROUP BY`, so only one row would be displayed anyway.